# Google Sign-in identify account tied to a school

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-signin, google-classroom

I'm using Google Sign-in to register and login users to my web app.

We are an edtech product, so I would like to make sure users are registering with a google account that is tied to a school and not using their personal google accounts.

Is this possible?

I don't see a field in `user` that would indicate this. I also can't find confirmation as to whether or not school google accounts can have an @gmail.com email or if they must use a custom domain.

Note that these account may or may not be using Google Classroom, so I can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a List of the "school" accounts and can test against that there is no way for you to know.

Google is not going to tell you if its a school google account.  They may know if its a google classroom account but that kind of information is not shared at login time.   Probably due to user privacy.